# Apache multiple virtual hosts same ServerName

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, virtualhost, wordpress, apache2

I want to use the same exact ServerName, but load the first virtualhost block that works.

**Here's how it should work:**

If there is a `wordpress` folder in `/var/www`  load that. Otherwise, load `index.html` in the `/var/www` directory.

Here is my config file with the 2 virtualhost blocks how I thought that would work. But it only works if I remove one or the other.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ServerAdmin my_email@email.com
    ServerName devsite.test

    <Directory "/var/www/wordpress">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerAdmin my_email@email.com
    ServerName devsite.test

    <Directory "/var/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The admin should be making this decision, not the web server.

Comment: Hi, I'm the admin this is for my VM that I develop and test on. Any ideas?

Comment: Change the configuration when you need to change it? use virtual machines and configuration management?

Comment: I guess I have to separate them into different URL's. Access my WordPress through `devsite.test/wordpress` and access a basic "load an index file" page on `/var/www`. Was hoping I could have it load from the wordpress if it exists. Thanks!

Comment: You have to separate with either ip or port, above thing will not work, virtual hosting work with port based, ip based or name based(DNS) you are not using any one of them. Let us know if you have some way to separate.

Comment: You certainly do not need to use two `<VirtualHost>` blocks. Try building an `if` condition: if this file/folder exists, put the `DocumentRoot` there, otherwise, do this. Though I wonder, why build this check? Are you adding/removing directories that often?